# Scale images down to an app optimized size using PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, image-processing, cakephp-2.7

I am working on an app where users can upload images (to my CakePHP 2.7.2 backend server) where they are stored. Those images are pretty big from time to time (e.g. iPhone images of about 7-8 MB).

The application shows those images in the app (but that takes very long because of the big data that has to be downloaded).

What is the best way of scaling images down to a size like 30kB using PHP? I want the images to be effective in size and quality. Important requirement is that the ration of width and height has to be kept!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/) PHP script.

> Adaptive Images detects your visitor's screen size and automatically creates, caches, and delivers device appropriate re-scaled versions of your web page's embeded HTML images. No mark-up changes needed. It is intended for use with Responsive Designs and to be combined with Fluid Image techniques.

**To make it work in CakePHP:**

1. Download it to your `/app/webroot/` folder
2. Modify you `/app/webroot/.htaccess` and add the following before the CakePHP mod_rewrite rules:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !optional_path_to_exclude/
   RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php [L]
   ```
3. Edit `/app/webroot/adaptive_images.php` and replace line 16:

   ```
   $cache_path    = "ai-cache";
   ```

   with

   ```
   $cache_path    = "/app/tmp/cache/ai-cache/";
   ```

   and line 30:

   ```
   $source_file    = $document_root.$requested_uri;
   ```

   with

   ```
   $source_file    = $document_root.'/app/webroot'.$requested_uri;
   ```

This last step may vary depending on your virtual host configuration.

Comment: That sounds very interestimg but probably might not work because I get my data via JSON API.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't. This only works for images stored as files in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to process images with PHP: [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).

For GD, rescaling an image is most easily accomplished with [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled). You'll need code roughly along these lines:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imageContents); //or one of the image imagecreatefrom* functions
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

ob_start();
imagepng($newImage, null); //or imagejpeg as appropriate
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

//do something with $output
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not answer the question. I don't know the new height and width.

Comment: The new height and width is going to depend on the file format, the original height and width, the file size, and how much it can be compressed. There's not a single simple answer for that. You're going to have to do some research and experimentation to determine exactly how much you need to rescale an image to meet a specific file size target.